# Springboot displays empty page

Tags: spring-boot

I created a spring boot system. The controller (RESTController) works fine, and I tested it using "System.out.println" and it shows correct data. With postman or browser I receive empty page, just display `[ {},{},{}]`. I used

```
ResponseEntity<List<MyClass>> fetchAllBlocks(){ 
return new ResponseEntity<List<MyClass>>(myservice.getAllBlocks(), HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

So, what is wrong?

Comment: Ensure that you have getters/setters. also show the relevent code.

Comment: Can you show the println and output that you say is giving you what you want ? The more code you share the more we have to go on.

Comment: Hereby the Controller class code

Comment: sorry, I will send the code in "Answer Your Question" section

Answer (score 0):

> The Controller code

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/block")
public class MyController {
    
  @Autowired
  private final MyServices myservice;
        
  @Autowired
  public MyController(MyServices myserv) {
    this.myservice = myserv;
  }
        
  @GetMapping("/all")
  public ResponseEntity<List<Block>> fetchAllBlocks() {
    List<Block> blocks = blockservice.getAllBlocks();
    ResponseEntity<List<Block>> response = new 
           ResponseEntity<List<Block>>(blocks, HttpStatus.OK);
    System.out.println("ALL " + response);
    return response;
  }
}
```

> The println output
> ALL <200 OK OK,[ID 6154d72eaddc4223646a9881 Header 1 Timestamp 2021-09-29T23:14:22.403 Data This is a test for Springboot, ID 6155aee934383f691fe109e1 Header 2 Timestamp 2021-09-30T14:34:48.984 Data and This is another test],[]>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but I used Intelij as my IDE instead of other and it worked. I used @AllArgsConstructor but it looks it wasn't working in the old IDE I used, because I added constructors and it didn't complain but Intelij complained about constructors and then it worked.
So, I will close the issue with thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).